# converting legacy spring mvc app tp spring mvc 4 app

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am converting a spring MVC 3 app to spring MVC 4 app so mostly I am converting it to annotation-based now there is a below xml file tag

```
 <context:component-scan
    base-package="life.mvc.framework.controller, ca.web.apps.exampleapp.controller" />
```

now what I have done inside this packages there are classes in which I have added these annotations as shown below

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({ "ca.web.apps.exampleapp.controller" })
```

and also in other package class, I have added as shown below

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({ "life.mvc.framework.controller"})
```

but when I deploy these changes to server the web pages are not opening and no error is also coming please advise what is the error that I am doing

Comment: Start with only upgrading Spring and leave your configuration. Then create a configuration class and one by one move things over from XML to Java don't do everything at once.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks sir for the reply can you show me one example i am still not able to grasp

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment. First make it work by only upgrading the Spring version (that should be a drop in replacement). Then add a `@Configuration` class to your project and add it as a `bean` to your xml configuration. Then slowly move the elements from your xml, one by one, to your `@Configuration` class. Do 1 thing at a time so that you still grasp what could be the issue. Finally when your xml is empty (apart from the config class) reconfigure your application to startup using the `@Configuration` class instead of XML. In short, take baby-steps instead of leaps.